# Drawing a line in Coco2D 2.0 iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a line sprite and invoke the draw function of CCSprite.

```
-(void) draw
{
 [super draw];
 ccDrawColor4F(....);
 ccDrawLine(...);
 }
```

The game works first time but subsequent relaunch of the game within the app would crashed

I took out this CCSprite and the issue goes away, so obvioysly this draw function of the CCSprite has issue.  How to fix that?

Comment: No there is nothing wrong there, need more details. Post the actual code in the function calls. Also what else have you overridden in CCSprite?

Comment: As soon as I commented out the contents inside draw then no more clashes. That's it. Only the draw method was overridden.

Comment: What kind of crash was it, you need to show the code that you have replaced with ....

Comment: crashed, EXEC_BAD_ACCESS, that's it. The ccDrawColor4F and ccDrawLine functions shown above are the ones I added.

Comment: Yes you need to show the actual function arguments. The bits of code you have replaced with ... above.